# How to accomplish this if then statement with less repetition?

Tags: php

I have something simple I'm trying to accomplish with less repetition.

By default, I want a div to be shown, however if $x == 1, then check to see if $y != 1, and if $y doesn't, then don't show the block.

However the best I can come up with is the following:

```
if($x) {

    if($y != 1) {

        echo '<div>display block</div>';        
    }

} else {

    echo '<div>display block</div>';

}
```

This seems a bit repetitive.

I know I can tweak it a bit and do something like:

```
$displayBlock = '<div>display block</div>';

if($x) {

    if($y != 1) {

        echo $displayBlock;     
    }

} else {

    echo $displayBlock;

}
```

But even still, I have a feeling that there is a way to do this whole if if else thing which I can't see right now.

How do you accomplish the above with less if statements? So: if $x != 1 (default), then show the displayBlock. if $x == 1, and $y != 1, then show the display block. If $x == 1 && $y == 1, then do *not* show the displayBlock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
if (!$x || $y != 1) echo $displayBlock;
```

Comment: Oh no, just 5 minutes left to rep-cap reset :-(

Comment: it seems to easy to be true 0.o (trying it now)

Comment: Do we *need* to write these one-liners? Why can't we make it easier to read?

Comment: @Incognito: it is easy to read for me :-S It is trivial condition, isn't it?

Comment: It's trivial, but it's harder to follow, PHP isn't a language that's structured on white space exclusively like Python is. Braces leave no room for misinterpretation when the maintainer that did't write the code needs to read it.

Comment: @Incognito: `harder to follow` is very subjective way to measure. As of your case, for example, it is hard *for me* to follow that lot of parentheses (yes, 3 parentheses in the begin of your code make me sad)

Comment: o.O Now I'm confused. Are you looking for ground to argue with me on here or are you genuine in your confusion that *more* structured operators bring, rather than ones from implied whitespace rules and logical operator precedence?

Comment: @Incognito: explicit paretheses aren't always good, so, yes, I prefer `$x && $y != 1` to `($x) && ($y != 1)`, just because a lot of parentheses `(((` force my eyes to look up for pair parentheses and return back to re-read expression within, instead just reading the expression left-to-right

Comment: I'm with zerkms on this one. The shortened operator here is much easier to understand in this case. Obviously it may vary depending on the conditions and how nested they get. I don't really understand your point about whitespace though.

Comment: My issue with operator precedence is minor, and mostly there because it's not the same over different languages. A maintainer who's coming from, lets say, VB, might not pick up right away some of the odd rules in there. My real concern is same-line decision structures, where white-space ends up controlling the flow.

Comment: ps: probably it is because I remember from math classes that `a && b || !a` can be reduced to `!a || b`

Comment: My brain literally turned inside out working out how this works. thans for the upgrade.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to zerkms's answer - it's on the money. To help you solve problems like this in the future, it might be handy to look at <strike>[truth tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table)</strike> [Karnaugh maps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map).

You essentially have two checks:

a) `$x` (coerced to true or false)
b) `$y != 1`

```
    $y != 1
      T  F
$x T  1  0
   F  1  1
```

So, from that you can see that if `$x` is falsey, or `$y != 1` is true, then you should show the display block, hence:

```
if (!$x || $y != 1) echo $displayBlock;
```

Comment: That's a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), not a truth table.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams cheers! looks like we're all learning something here today.

Answer (score 2):

In order to keep the amount of code down, you could use a more mathematical approach rather than logic; e.g.

```
<?php

if($x+$y != 2){echo $displayBlock;}

?>
```

The display box only stays off when the sum of x and y equals 2.

Answer (score 1):

Check these out. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php

```
$displayBlock = '<div>display block</div>';

if((($x) && ($y != 1)) || (!$x)) {
    echo $displayBlock;
}
```

How did we come to this solution?

Look at your statement, and dissect it logically:

`If x is true` ... `and`  ... `y is 1`... then print.

Which brings us to:

`(($x) && ($y != 1))`

See? X is truth AND y is one. That brigns you down to

```
if (($x) && ($y != 1)) {
    //Do that thing
} else {
    if (! $x) {
        //Do that thing 
    }
}
```

Which we can write simply as...

```
if (($x) && ($y != 1)) {
    //Do that thing
} else { if (! $x) {
    //Do that thing 
}
```

Okay, so what's this say?

If `conditionA` do something, `or` if condition B do something.

Oh, there's an OR.

So, `condtion A || condition B`

Which of course, brings us back to...

```
if((($x) && ($y != 1)) || (!$x)) {
```

I put in more braces than required in there so you can see the flow of things.

Comment: I appreciate you explaining that so much @incognito